# get_page_by_title() doesn't retrieve my post

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a CPT called "patchwork" and I created a post of this type entitled "Patchwork 01". The following code should retrieve this post, but it doesn't.

```
$patchwork = get_page_by_title( 'Patchwork 01', 'patchwork' );    
echo $patchwork->ID;
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter for `get_page_by_title()` is `$output`, with the third being `$post_type`.

This should solve your porblem -

```
$patchwork = get_page_by_title( 'Patchwork 01', OBJECT, 'patchwork' );    
echo $patchwork->ID;
```

Please have a look at the [Function Reference for `get_page_by_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) for more information.